Does WSLv2 work on ARM64 devices?
Can WSLv2 be installed on ARM64 machines?  I am looking to get the Surface Laptop 7 ARM64 CoPilot laptop.   I use WSLv2 a lot.
Thanks

Can WSLv2 be installed on ARM64 machines?
Yes:

WSL 2 is only available in 64-bit Windows 10 version 1903 build 18362.1049 or higher, OR Windows 10 version 2004 build 19041 or higher for ARM64 systems.

Source: How to Update from WSL to WSL 2 in Windows 10 | Tutorials

Further Reading:

How to Enable WSL and Install Linux on Windows


I got Ubuntu 18.04 to work on it.  Converted it to WSLv2
This is on a Surface Laptop 7 ARM64 CoPilot laptop

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
